# FedL - raise ValueError, "dataset must be 'testing' or 'training'"

Tags: python, tensorflow-federated

Currently I'm working on implementing code in "Differentially Private Federated Learning: A Client Level Perspective" where the GitHub link is [LINK](https://github.com/SAP-samples/machine-learning-diff-private-federated-learning).
However, I follow the instruction but got an error which is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 5, in <module>
    from MNIST_reader import Data
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab_Notebooks/machine-learning-diff-private-federated-learning-main/MNIST_reader.py", line 20
    raise ValueError, "dataset must be 'testing' or 'training'"
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I just run `bash RUNME.sh` and follow the instruction but still get an error!

```
!python sample.py —-m 100, sigma 1
```

You're welcome if you want to check the full code [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1TiejY0efe1gDsdvLNg9ePM3FVViWPtRj?usp=sharing).
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` may suggest that code is for `Python 2` but you runs `Python 3`. You may have to use `()` instead of `,` in line `raise ValueError("dataset must be 'testing' or 'training'")`

Comment: BTW: it should be `--m 100` instead of `—-m 100` (there is wrong first `-`)`

Answer (score 0):

Error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` for line

```
raise ValueError, "dataset must be 'testing' or 'training'"
```

may suggest that code was created for `Python 2` but you run `Python 3`.

You may have edit file `MNIST_read.py` and use `()` instead of `,` in line

```
raise ValueError("dataset must be 'testing' or 'training'")
```

---

**BTW:**

Some files on GitHub are 5 years old so it could be created for `Python 2`.
So you may excpect that code may have other problems with `Python 3`

Requirements shows `Tensorflow 1.4.1` and it may have problem to run with your `Tensorflow 2.8.4` because they change some elements.

Maybe it will be simpler to run it with `Python 2`

---

**EDIT:**

In GitHub in [Insight / Network](https://github.com/SAP-samples/machine-learning-diff-private-federated-learning/network) you can see all forks of this repo and fork created by [rosdyana](https://github.com/rosdyana/machine-learning-diff-private-federated-learning) has last commit with title `Fix code for python3.5` and maybe you should use this version.

But this version still may need to use `Tensorflow 1.4.1` which may need older Python `3.5` or `3.6`. I don't know if it works with the newest versions of Python.